# error layout bootstrap gallery

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i've created bootstrap gallery and it work well, but in small screen this problem occurs and the design will be bad in medium screen.
can anyone help me to solve this problem
the problem is occurs because of large centered image, so how to improve the ddesign layout !!

```css
.our-gallery .margin-bottom{
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
.our-gallery .overlay-gallery{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgb(254, 88, 149);
    opacity:0;
    text-align:center;
    transition:opacity .3s linear;
    padding:10px;
}
.our-gallery .img-thumb{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.our-gallery .overlay-gallery:hover{opacity:.75;}
.our-gallery .overlay-gallery p{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:Consolas,Arial,'Comic Sans MS';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="our-gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 margin-bottom">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151645.jpg?itok=yY0PVMkG" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Blush peonies made up the romantic bridal bouquet. 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-thumb">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Polina topped her loose, romantic waves with a lush floral crown. She also wore pearl earrings and a bracelet that were gifts from her husband-to-be.    
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151643.jpg?itok=ceG1BJ1L" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Polina, a photographer and jewelry designer based in Russia, met Robertas, an entrepreneur born and raised in Lithuania before moving to South Carolina after college, while in the United States during a student exchange program with her native country. The pair met at a friend's beach house party and immediately hit it off. "It just so happens that I'd learned the Russian language in school, and it made it so much easier to communicate," said Robertas. After a wonderful summer together, Polina had to return to Russia, but "we did not want to lose each other and, against all odds, started a long-distance relationship," recalled Robertas. After dating for two years, Robertas proposed during a hot air balloon ride over a lake in Europe. They tied the knot one year later in an intimate celebration with ten of their closest friends and family members, including Robertas' family from Lithuania and Polina's family from Russia.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Polina helped design her own wedding dress, which was custom-made in Europe. 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="img-thumb">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Before the ceremony, the couple had a first look. "Polina took my breath away," recalled Robertas.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                The couple chose Litchfield Plantation for their celebration due to its Southern charm, romance, and intimacy.                            
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                The couple exchanged personalized vows in their native language.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                During the ceremony, the couple asked their parents to join them for the lighting of a unity candle, which symbolizes two families coming together.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Here, the couple poses beneath the weeping willows.                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                The two-tier vanilla cake featured a strawberry filling.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Robertas' peony boutonniere coordinated perfectly with Polina's bridal crown.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Photos from the couple's engagement session adorned a vintage door near the guest 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Additional desserts included cultural favorites, like Oreshki (a cookie baked in a walnut mold and filled with dulce de leche), a Luthianian cake that's "stacked like a Christmas tree," and traditional wedding spice cookies.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                "Many shouts of 'gorko, gorko' were heard throughout the night, signaling that the bride and groom must kiss!" recalled their wedding planner.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                For the intimate dinner party, wedding planner Gigi Noelle Events enhanced the natural beauty of the surroundings with a tent frame draped with sheer white fabric. Vintage bird cages, soft flowers, and a chandelier overhead accented the table.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                The couple shared a special dance to "Moon River." "It's timeless," said the groom.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                The newlyweds' advice to engaged couples: "It really helps if you have a strong vision, and don't be afraid to try something new."
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Very bad pictures. :P

Comment: Bootstrap is not always enough to make a fully responsive layout. You need to use some media query as well to make it fully responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a try. you can adjust margins etc for yourself.

```css
.our-gallery .margin-bottom{
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
.our-gallery .overlay-gallery{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgb(254, 88, 149);
    opacity:0;
    text-align:center;
    transition:opacity .3s linear;
    padding:10px;
    z-index: 999999;
}
.our-gallery .img-thumb{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
.our-gallery .overlay-gallery:hover{opacity:.75;}
.our-gallery .overlay-gallery p{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:Consolas,Arial,'Comic Sans MS';
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
img{
width:100%;
max-width:none;
}
.half-class{
width: 50% !important;
float:left;
}
@media  only screen and (max-width: 756px){
.half-class{
width: 100% !important;
float:none;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="our-gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom half-class">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151645.jpg?itok=yY0PVMkG" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Blush peonies made up the romantic bridal bouquet. 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-thumb half-class">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Polina topped her loose, romantic waves with a lush floral crown. She also wore pearl earrings and a bracelet that were gifts from her husband-to-be.    
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151643.jpg?itok=ceG1BJ1L" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Polina, a photographer and jewelry designer based in Russia, met Robertas, an entrepreneur born and raised in Lithuania before moving to South Carolina after college, while in the United States during a student exchange program with her native country. The pair met at a friend's beach house party and immediately hit it off. "It just so happens that I'd learned the Russian language in school, and it made it so much easier to communicate," said Robertas. After a wonderful summer together, Polina had to return to Russia, but "we did not want to lose each other and, against all odds, started a long-distance relationship," recalled Robertas. After dating for two years, Robertas proposed during a hot air balloon ride over a lake in Europe. They tied the knot one year later in an intimate celebration with ten of their closest friends and family members, including Robertas' family from Lithuania and Polina's family from Russia.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom half-class">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Polina helped design her own wedding dress, which was custom-made in Europe. 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="img-thumb half-class">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Before the ceremony, the couple had a first look. "Polina took my breath away," recalled Robertas.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                The couple chose Litchfield Plantation for their celebration due to its Southern charm, romance, and intimacy.                            
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                The couple exchanged personalized vows in their native language.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                During the ceremony, the couple asked their parents to join them for the lighting of a unity candle, which symbolizes two families coming together.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Here, the couple poses beneath the weeping willows.                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                The two-tier vanilla cake featured a strawberry filling.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Robertas' peony boutonniere coordinated perfectly with Polina's bridal crown.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Photos from the couple's engagement session adorned a vintage door near the guest 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                Additional desserts included cultural favorites, like Oreshki (a cookie baked in a walnut mold and filled with dulce de leche), a Luthianian cake that's "stacked like a Christmas tree," and traditional wedding spice cookies.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                "Many shouts of 'gorko, gorko' were heard throughout the night, signaling that the bride and groom must kiss!" recalled their wedding planner.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                For the intimate dinner party, wedding planner Gigi Noelle Events enhanced the natural beauty of the surroundings with a tent frame draped with sheer white fabric. Vintage bird cages, soft flowers, and a chandelier overhead accented the table.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                The couple shared a special dance to "Moon River." "It's timeless," said the groom.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="img-thumb margin-bottom">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bridalguide.com/sites/default/files/styles/600x800/public/rw-images/269-151638.jpg?itok=GC1q2tH6" alt="fw_il_013_01" data-animation="animated rotateInDownLeft" />
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <p>
                                The newlyweds' advice to engaged couples: "It really helps if you have a strong vision, and don't be afraid to try something new."
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```